# Associatons between two models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, associations

Thank you for visiting. I'm still new to connecting models and have a question. I have two models currently:

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "first_name"
 t.string   "last_name"
 t.string   "email"
 t.string   "password_digest"
 t.string   "user_name"
 t.date     "birthdate"
 t.integer  "zip_code"
 t.string   "gender"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.string   "avatar_file_name"
 t.string   "avatar_content_type"
 t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
 t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
 t.string   "background_file_name"
 t.string   "background_content_type"
 t.integer  "background_file_size"
 t.datetime "background_updated_at"
 t.string   "slug"
end

create_table "user_avatars", force: true do |t|
 t.integer  "user_id"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.string   "avatar_file_name"
 t.string   "avatar_content_type"
 t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
 t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
end
```

As you can see the User model is getting really long and someone told me before it's better if I separate avatar to a separate model. My question is how will I be able to change a user profile information without having two separate Form_for fields? Since I would like for a user to be able to edit there user_name, first_name etc and also UserAvatar.avatar at the same time. Thank you for all the help and those who help me learn something new.

For more information please ask

**User model**

```
has_one :user_avatar

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
 :medium => "200x200>",
 :small => "120x120#",
 :thumb => "75x75#",
 :default_url => "http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png"
   }

validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

**UserAvatar model**

```
belongs_to :user

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
 :medium => "200x200>",
 :small => "120x120#",
 :thumb => "75x75#",
 :default_url => "http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png"
   }

validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

**Views = Users/index**

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_path(current_user), html: { method: :put, :multipart => true } do |f| %>
 <p class="editpage">Profile Picture: <%= f.file_field :avatar %></p>
 <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What do you mean by two separate Form_for fields? Like two submit buttons?

Answer (score 1):

You can use do it like this:

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user_avatar
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_avatar, allow_destroy: true
end

class UserAvatar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => {
    :medium => "200x200>",
    :small => "120x120#",
    :thumb => "75x75#",
    :default_url => "http://www.adtechnology.co.uk/images/UGM-default-user.png"
  }

  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: user_path(current_user), html: { method: :put, :multipart => true } do |f| %>
  <%= fields_for @user.user_avatar do |user_avatar_form| %>
    <p class="editpage">Profile Picture: <%= user_avatar_form.file_field :avatar %></p>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload" %>
<% end %>
```

You can also check http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for and http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've just learned that you got some bad advice.

What was the basis for separating them out? It has made your code more complex and therefore error prone.

I think the best step you could take is to revert to a single model.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to revert to a single model or if you are using seperate model for avatar then use fields_for concept
[watch it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)